# Django Filtering Search Results using GET

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I would like to build a filter for my ListView, to further narrow down the search results.

Currently, the user searches for services in their area and chooses between paid or free service (Using radio buttons).

**forms.py:**

```
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    Place = forms.CharField(label='Place')
    Lat = forms.FloatField()
    Lng = forms.FloatField()
    CHOICES = [('Free', 'Paid'),
               ('Free', 'Paid')]
    Type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    SearchRadius = forms.IntegerField()
```

**views.py:**

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    if self.request.method == 'GET':
        form = LocationForm(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            SearchPoint=Point(form.cleaned_data['Lng'],form.cleaned_data['Lat'])
            Radius = form.cleaned_data['SearchRadius']
            Type = form.cleaned_data['Type']
        else:
            form = LocationForm()
            SearchPoint=Point(0,0)
            Radius = 15
            Type='Free'
        try:
            Type
        except:
            vt_filter = "'Free'=True"
        else:
            if Type == 'Free':
                vt_filter="'Free'=True"
            else:
                vt_filter="'Paid'=True"



    context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    res = Model.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=
                                 (SearchPoint, D(km=Radius)),vt_filter)\
        .annotate(distance=Distance('location', SearchPoint))\
        .order_by('distance')

    context['model_list'] = res
    context['form'] = form

    return context
```

I wanted to add something similar to `.filter('Free'=True)` to further narrow down the results.

In my **models.py**, for the `Model`, I have Boolean fields for Free and Paid respectively.

```
Free = models.BooleanField(default=True)
Paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

It seems that `vt_filter`, which is the additional filter I want to run to distinguish between free and paid services doesn't work, and gives me this error: `too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: Hey, @Roma I was wondering, did you find my answer helpful?

Comment: Hi John, yes, I've marked it correct

Comment: good to know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a string to pass arguments to the `.filter()` method.

What you can do instead is to add it in a dictionary:

```
vt_filter = {
    'Free': True,
}
```

and then pass it by [unpacking](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/dict_unpack.html) it into the filter:

```
res = Model.objects.filter(
          **vt_filter,
          location__distance_lte=(SearchPoint, D(km=Radius))
      ).annotate(distance=Distance('location', SearchPoint))
      .order_by('distance')
```

---

***Note:***

As a design concern, a service can be either *free* or *paid*. Therefore you can omit the `Paid` field of your model and use only the `Free` since if a service is free then `Free=True` else `Free=False`.

Also, it is better for your code readability to use [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) standards to name your stuff. (For example, `SearchPoint` should be `search_point` etc.)